# Set default value of dropdown list in angularjs materials

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have this simple webpage done in angularjs materials v1 as shown below;

[image]

Here is the html code;

```
<div ng-controller="room_controller" class="md-padding" ng-cloak layout="column">
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">Room settings</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                <span>Room</span>
                <md-select ng-model="mode" placeholder="Mode1" class="md-no-underline">
                    <md-option value="auto">Mode1</md-option>
                    <md-option value="manual">Mode2</md-option>
                </md-select>
                <md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
                    <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                    <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                    <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
                </md-select>
            </div>
        </md-card-content>
    <md-card>
</div>
```

The angularjs controller code is as follows;

```
.controller('room_controller', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

    }])
```

I want the default option of the dropbox list in the centre to be `"manual"`. As a result, the text `Mode2` will appear at the dropbox list by default.

Comment: `$scope.mode = 'manual'`

Comment: Just that only? So simple? Let me try it out. I feel really stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **`ng-model`**  in controller and set the `mode` as manual

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mode = 'manual'

});
```

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mode = 'manual'

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>Test angular md-select with material 0.11.0</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />


  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
      <span>Room</span>
      <md-select ng-model="mode" placeholder="Mode1" class="md-no-underline">
        <md-option value="auto">Mode1</md-option>
        <md-option value="manual">Mode2</md-option>
      </md-select>
      <md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
        <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
        <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
        <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div layout="row">
    return value: {{mode}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it 'better', in your controller you should have

```
.controller('room_controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modes = [
        { val: 'auto', label: 'Mode 1' },
        { val: 'manual', label: 'Mode 2' }
    ]

    // Selected value
    $scope.selectedMode = { val: 'manual', label: 'Mode 2' };
}])
```

and render your html like this:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedMode" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.val'}">
  <md-option ng-value="mode" ng-repeat="mode in modes">{{ mode.label }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/razvanbalosin/a6m076y4/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add one line `$scope.mode = 'manual'` to your angularjs controller.

```
.controller('room_controller', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.mode = 'manual'
    }])
```